# Python: Regular expression for quadratic equations

Tags: python, regex

I am currently trying to do a quadratic equation solver. I searched on the web how people did their version, but all of them implied that the user entered the coefficients, which, although the easiest way, I really hate it.

I want the user to introduce the whole equation, and let the program know which are the coefficients, and calculate the solution. I discovered the concept of regex, and automatically, the re module.

I understand how to implement the quadratic formula to solve the problem, but the problem is that I don't know which function should I use, and how to get the coefficients from the input.

I want the regex to be like:

`\d(\sx\s\(\^)\s2/x\^2)(\s\+\s)\dbx(\s\+\s)\d = 0`

To find the coefficients in this:

`ax^2 + bx + c = 0`

I am aware that the regex sucks, because I only started to understand it yesterday, so you can also tell me how to improve that.

---

### EDIT:

Let's clarify what I exactly want.

1. How to improve the regex that I tried doing above?
2. What Python function should I use so that I can only have the coefficients?
3. How can I take the groups and turn them into usable integers, assuming that it doesn't store those groups?

Comment: To my view you need to write a parser, or restrict the user to enter values in a very specific manner to be able to split it with string functions. In either case - regular expressions are not the way.

Comment: To properly parse a mathematical formula, you really need to build an expression tree.  But, I suppose for something simple like this, where you only support one specific formula, it's possible to use regex.  But you never really describe what the problem is that you are having?  What exactly is your question?

Comment: > I understand how to implement the quadratic formula to solve the problem, but the problem is that I don't know which function should I use, and how to get the coefficients from the input.

Comment: So you're question isn't about how to create a working regex pattern.  You question is about how to call the regex engine from python and read the results out from it?

Comment: There's no reason to input `ax^2 + bx + c = 0`, just to extract `a`, `b`, and `c`, when the user can simply just input `a`, `b`, and `c` alone.

Comment: I'm trying to help you formulate your question so that you get the answer you need.  The StackOverflow community has specific rules about the kinds of questions that are on topic and well received and those which are not.  Right now, your question is not very specific or clear.  It's a bit too broad.  It would be better if you could break your problems into separate specific questions.  The idea is not to just have someone provide you with a working solution by doing the work for you, but by answering specific questions to help you as you solve it yourself.

Comment: I know how to implement that, but since I discovered regex, why not use them? That's like learning about git, yet not ever using it.

@StevenDoggart, I will edit my post into separate questions

Comment: I edited my post, go and check it out.

Comment: @StefanAlecu, regex are useful and it's important to spend some time mastering them - but they shouldn't be your first choice for most problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumptions: the coefficients are numbers and the variable is `x`:

```
(-?\d+)x\^2 ([+-]\d+)x ([+-]\d+)
```

Now for `-3x^2 +7x -44` your first group match will be `-3`, second group will be `+7` and third group will be `-44`.

- Round brackets (`()`) define a group
- `?` says that what was followed can be matched one or zero times
- `[+-]` defines a character set that will match either a `+` or a `-` one time

---

**EDIT**: Start to end solution (*excuse my rusty python skills, but I hope you get an idea of how to use the regex*):

```
import re

quadratic_equation_matcher = re.compile(r'(-?\d+)x\^2 ([+-]\d+)x ([+-]\d+)')
quadratic_equation = '-3x^2 +7x -44'
matches = quadratic_equation_matcher.match(quadratic_equation)
a = int(matches.group(1))
b = int(matches.group(2))
c = int(matches.group(3))
d = b**2 - 4*a*b
x1 = (-b + d**0.5)/(2*a)
x2 = (-b - d**0.5)/(2*a)
x1 # => -0.75542709911179939
x2 # => 3.0887604324451328
```

---

Note that you can make the regex more space permissive like so:

```
(-? ?\d+) ?x\^2 ([+-] ?\d+) ?x ([+-] ?\d+)
```

Comment: Or, for *"space permissiveness"*, instead of `?`, you could use `\s*`, which would allow any number of any whitespace characters

Comment: This is good, but there is a problem: in `-3x^2 +7x -44`, yes, it does the job, but the solution kinda depends on the +- there, so I would also like the regex to recognize that and put it in a separate group, like the others.

Comment: @StefanAlecu, sorry, I didn't get your comment. The `+`/`-` will be part of the second/third group. What is your concern and what do you want to put in a separate group?

Comment: As you can see, it matters when you want to solve it.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Quadratic_formula.svg/402px-Quadratic_formula.svg.png

Comment: *"when you want to solve it"*? I know the quadratic formula xd Here **a** will be the match in the first group (`-3`), **b** will be the match in the second group (`+7`) and **c** will be the match in the third group (`-44`). Still don't get what you mean.

Comment: Actually, if I think about it, yeah, you are right, it's useless to count the operator. Check my edit.

Comment: Finally, someone who answered my questions. Thanks, sir.

Comment: Now I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I read about that, so I guess that it hadn't found anything.
I edited the code a bit to fit with my original program.
Oh, I also use 3.4.3 if it matters: 

http://pastebin.com/KPmfJRSM

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend cleaning the input up a but first. Get rid of all the white space, or at least the spaces. Check for an equal sign and see if there's a 0 on one side or the other. If there is you can remove it. If not you have to decide how clever you want to be.

Get it close to a format you want to deal with, in other words. Then you can check if they've entered a valid re.

You also need to decide if you can handle shuffling the order of the terms around and letters other than x. Also whether you want the ^ or ** or just x2.

You probably want to grab each term individually (all the terms between the + or -) and decide what kind of term it is.

In other words there's a lot to do before the re expression.

Incidentally have you seen SymPy

Comment: @stefan, you're right. I wasn't really trying to answer the question. My bad. Just trying to present a few of the challenges with the OP's approach

Comment: No, man, it actually seems like a good alternative, and I researched it, and it seems great, I will research if it has quadratic equations in there.